# Pandas DataFrame.itertuples() auto casts objects dtypes to date and time dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm using Dask and PyOrc to write Data from database tables in ORC Files.
In order to specify correct dtypes, i'm using the *meta* parameter `read_sql_table`.
My version of Pandas is 1.2.1

And here is an extract of my code :

```
kwargs = dict(
            table=fetch_object_name,
            index_col=fetch_index_col,
            uri=uri,
            meta=dask_meta,
            columns=list(dask_meta.columns)
        )
dask_stream = dd.read_sql_table(**kwargs)
print(dask_stream.dtypes)

dask_stream.map_partitions(
                write_to_orc,
                data_path,
                meta=dask_meta
            ).compute()
```

It returns

```
IDX01             Int64
IDX02             Int64
COL01            object
COL02            object
COL03             Int64
COL04             Int64
COL05             Int64
COL06             Int64
COL07           float64
COL08           float64
COL09           float64
COL10            object
COL11            object
COL12    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

In the write_to_orc function, I want to iterate over rows in order to write them into a file, but I got this strange behavior when I want to print the lines:

```
def write_to_orc(df, data_path):
    print(df.dtypes)
    for row in df.itertuples():
        print(row)
```

I got :

```
IDX01             Int64
IDX02             Int64
COL01            object
COL02            object
COL03             Int64
COL04             Int64
COL05             Int64
COL06             Int64
COL07           float64
COL08           float64
COL09           float64
COL10            object
COL11            object
COL12    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
Pandas(Index=1, IDX01=1400101, IDX02=447, COL01='Dim   ', COL02='1 Dimanche 2040 (Q1)', COL03=98, COL04=-19191, COL05=21082041, COL06=-6071621782820847456, COL07=3131.25, COL08=-1e+121, COL09=4.775582863893604e+18, COL10=datetime.date(1987, 6, 17), COL11=datetime.time(2, 11, 50), COL12=Timestamp('2012-04-27 13:02:23.860000'))
```

It seems that the dtypes are good but the COL10 and COL11 columns values have the wrong types. Somehow Pandas converts them to date and time (and at any time I have given to pandas the date and time formats), despite the related dtypes are object !!

It bothers me a lot because TIME is not a recognized type for ORC, that's why I wanted to be handled as a string.

Can you help me understanding this strange behaviour ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first output `COL10` and `COL11` are reported as `object` dtype, which suggests that they might be originally cast as `datetime` objects in `dask_meta` (at least for some of the rows). As a way out of this you could explicitly set these columns as `String` (the capitalized version is referring to the new dtype) in `dask_meta`.